# NMCLI connection only works with 1 wifi adapter

Tags: networkmanager, nmcli, armbian

I have 2 wifi adapters on my odroid, wlan0 and wlan1, I connected to my wifi using nmcli with wlan1 successfully, but would like to be able to connect with wlan0 instead. However it seems no matter what I do (both removing the connection and deleting it from the network manager) nmcli will only allow the first adapter (wlan1) to connect to the connection. When I try the same command but replacing wlan1 with wlan0

`nmcli d wifi connect <ssid> --ask ifname wlan0`

it gives me this
`Error: Connection activation failed: (7) Secrets were required, but not provided.`

but running the same command using wlan1 connects no issue. Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

Also these are 2 identical adapters, both confirmed working before, just cant 'swap' them on my wifi for some reason.

Extra info: Using odroid c4 with Armbian 22.11

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was to completely remove an already present instance of the connection first and then re-add it, restarting the NetworkManager in the process. For example:

```
nmcli connection show           # is your <ssid> present?
nmcli connection delete <ssid>  # then delete it
systemctl restart NetworkManager.service
nmcli device wifi connect <ssid> password <password>
nmcli connection reload
nmcli connection up <ssid>
```

This also solved the error message in the logfile
`CTRL-EVENT-ASSOC-REJECT ...status_code=16` that was assoicated with a wrong password (although the same password leading to this error works fine, after following the above listed steps).